# How do you track templates calls in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion

How do you track template path in ColdFusion?

I.E.
I have the following folder and file structure

- index.cfm

  `<cfset ArrayAppend(request.Trace, '/')>
   <cfdump var=#request.trace#>`
- **foo**

  - index.cfm

    `<cfset ArrayAppend(request.Trace, '/foo/')>
    <cfinclude template='../'>`
  - **bar**

    - index.cfm

      `ArrayAppend(request.Trace,'/foo/bar/')>
      <cfinclude template='../'>`

When I call `foo/bar/index.cfm`,
request.Trace equals:

- '/foo/bar/'
- '/foo/'
- '/'

How could I do this without specifically declaring each folder name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at:

- `expandPath(".")`
- `getBaseTemplatePath()`
- `getCurrentTemplatePath()`
- `CGI.CF_TEMPLATE_PATH`
- `CGI.PATH_TRANSLATED`
- `CGI.SCRIPT_NAME`

If you want the template stack trace, use this:

```
<cfset templateTrace = []>
<cfset tagTrace = createObject("java","java.lang.Exception").init().TagContext>
<cfloop array="#tagTrace#" index="tagInfo">
    <cfset templateTrace.add(tagInfo.Template)>
</cfloop>
<cfdump var="#templateTrace#">
```

This will output all templates passed up to this call.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. I updated the question to better fit the solution

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks @Alex it is really helpful in debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Not ideal but this worked for me.

```
<cfset currentFile = GetCurrentTemplatePath()>
<cfset currentDir = GetDirectoryFromPath(currentFile)>
<cfset webroot = expandPath("/")>
<cfset m_Trace = Replace(currentDir, webroot , '\')>
<cfset ArrayAppend (request.Trace, m_Trace )>
```

Comment: I edited my post to include a way to retrieve the template stack trace without the need to place code in every template.